# how to prevent scrollbar from pushing elements?

Tags: html, css, sass, materialize

I use the materialize CSS framework and I have a custom search bar with a width of 100vw for the mobile screen, it works well if without a scrollbar, when the scrollbar appears my searchbar is pushed to the left as shown below.

**without scrollbar**

[image: without scrollbar]

**with scrollbar**

[image: with scrollbar]

**width 100%**

[image: Width 100%]

**I mean it is like the picture below**

The searchbar on stackoverflow can adjust the width of the screen

[image]
[image]

**navbar**

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger show-on-small">
      <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
    </a>
    <a href="/" class="brand-logo center">
      <img src="images/personal-logo-full.png" height="40">
    </a>
    <div class="searchbar right">
      <form action="#" method="POST" autocomplete="off" class="search-wrapper">
        <div class="search-field" :class="{ active: searchIsActive }">
          <a class="search-icon" @click="openSearch"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>
          <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search" class="browser-default search-input" v-model="searchText">
          <a class="close-icon" @click="closeSearch"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**style**

```
// materialize default
nav .nav-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

// custom
.searchbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.search-wrapper, .search-field {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.search-field {
  height: 34px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  @media #{$large-and-up} {
    margin: 0;
  }
  &.active {
    width: calc(100vw - 20px);
    background-color: #F5F6F7;
    @media #{$large-and-up} {
      width: 300px;
      margin: 0 15px;
    }
  }
  .search-input {
    width: inherit;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 0 8px;
  }
  a {
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color .2s;
  }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code we could just guess: have you tried to set the width to 100% instead of 100vw ?

Comment: @fcalderan yes, but it doesn't make the search bar full width

Comment: This is expected behavior from the browser. Why is this a problem?

Comment: @DanielWilliams because the search bar is pushed to the left, look at the second picture, I don't expect that

Comment: Please provide all the relevant code in a working example so people can take a better look at what you are trying to do. Besides that, what @DanielWilliams is trying to say is that the browser should behave this way, because where would else would the scrollbar be positioned? This is how a website should be viewed. The only way to prevent this is to make your scrollbar invisible, which is  far from ideal.

Comment: If you try to view this page on a mobile device, your scroll will not overlap in the search bar. You can use mobile view in [chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/).

Comment: Use percentage widths instead of vw - 100vw is the width of the viewport so when the scrollbar takes up 20px, vw still counts the scrollbar as part of the viewport, where as percentage just takes up the available space

Comment: Why cant you just use 100% or better still flex. calc and vw isn't great for support.

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I mean that the width of the search bar can be flexible, like the searchbar on stackoverflow, I have edited the question and added an example image

Answer (score -1):

You have a custom search bar with a width of 100vw for the mobile screen...

Try using `width: 100%;`

100vw takes the viewport width, which includes the scrollbar

Also you can use `width: calc(100vw - 13px)` if I remember correctly the scrollbar is 13px in the general case, but this is a hacky way of doing it.

EDIT:

You know mobile devices do not actually show the scrollbar, right.

If you are only testing on resized browser, and you don't care about that, because not many people do it, you can just forget about it.

If you want to see genuine mobile behavior use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to access a local website online.